Searching for a title to a sci-fi movie that had a telepathic dolphin
I have a vague memory of a movie I once saw as a kid that I cannot remember. This must have been close to 16 years ago. But I would imagine the movie was probably made between the 70s and 80s.
The movie was definitely a science fiction film. In the scene I remember most; the main character finds himself in a secure location (junkyard/ wasteland) of a leader of some rebellion/insurgent army. In the scene, there is a dolphin who is in a small tank and has a neurological headset on that allows him to communicate with the main character. In that same scene the bad guys find the location of the hideout and begin destroying the place. Someone has to remember a dolphin in a small tank communicating telepathically.

This is Johnny Mnemonic. The Dolphin is Jones, a ex-navy cybernetically enhanced dolphin for submarine warfare, who is now a sentient hacker. Keanu needs Jones to hack his own brain!



Jones is not telepathic per se, it's using cybernetics in himself and in the main character who has a cybernetic memory unit in his head. It's computer networking.
The scene plays out exactly as you describe it. Secure location gets raided shortly after.

Awesome. That's it. People were telling me that I was making up the story. Like I said, it has been awhile. Thank you.

This movie sounds... peculiar :D
